# How to move newly added picklist value from sandbox to test system

Tags: deployment, global-picklist

I have made changed in the global picklist.

Now, I wanted to move the changes from one sandbox to another sandbox.

How to move newly added picklist value from sandbox to test system.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to deploy the whole global picklist.

For this you can either use [Change Set](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_about_outbound.htm&type=5):

create an outbound change set, look for the global picklist under "Global Value Set" and add it as component to the outbound changeset. Then you can upload the change set to the other sandbox.

Or you can use [ANT migration tool](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_tools_ant_using.htm&type=5) :

use the following package.xml file to retrieve the global picklist then deploy it to the target sandbox. You will have to replace "APINameOfComponent" by the API name of your global picklist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">  
    <types>
        <members>APINameOfComponent</members>
        <name>GlobalValueSet</name>
    </types>
    <version>45.0</version>
</Package>
```